# MikTeX 2.9 installs polyglossia in a different location than where it looks for it

Tags: packages, miktex, polyglossia

I recently did a complete reinstall of Windows 7, installed all updates, and reinstalled all of my programs, including MikTeX using the 2.9 64-bit version. I ran a XeLaTeX document I had created and successfully run before, in order to re-download and autoinstall most of my packages. This went well, except for **polyglossia.sty** and **gloss-english.ldf**, both parts of the **polyglossia** package; MikTeX prompts popped up (I had set the autoinstall on "ask me" at install) twice for the first file and three times for the second, before moving on and generating the document anyway. The same thing would happen with those two every time I ran the document; I tried changing the autoinstall download from "random" to, eventually, a dozen or so repositories with no better luck. I looked in the directory cited in the autoinstall prompt, and still no **polyglossia** directory.

Thinking perhaps it was a glich in the 64-bit version of MikTeX, I uninstalled it--successfully except that Windows was for some reason unable to remove the empty **MikTeX 2.9** directory from **Program Files (86)**--I removed it myself, but had to assert administrator privilege to do so. I then ran CCleaner on the Windows registry; there were fixes to be made, but none that appeared to have anything to do with MikTeX. I then downloaded the 32-bit version and installed it, but everything just went as before. And I don't even want to think about the manual download-and-install fiasco that I tried next; it seems you can't get **polyglossia.sty** to extract from **polyglossia.dtx** without **polyglossia.sty** installed first.

Then it occurred to me to look in ALL of my **C:\Program Files (x86)\MikTeX 2.9\tex** subdirectories, not just the **xelatex** subdirectory where MikTeX was looking for them, and lo and behold, there **polyglossia** was... in the **latex** subdirectory. For all I know, MikTeX was fetching it and putting it there every single time I clicked the go-get-it button. So the question becomes: do I either tell MikTeX where to put it (and how), or where it should be *looking* for it, (and again, how)? Or should I just move the **polyglossia** directory to 
**C:\Program Files (x86)\MikTeX 2.9\tex\xelatex** with a simple cut-and-paste and be done with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Polyglossia is in `\tex\latex\polyglossia\polyglossia.sty` in my miktex. As polyglossia is moving toward luatex this is the correct place and it works for me.

It sometimes happens that miktex gets confused about the location of a package (mostly when package are rearranged or moved to another location). In such case try at first to synchronize the package repository (package manager, menu repositories). If you have a multiuser installation do it in admin **and** in user mode. Also recreate the FNDB -- again as admin and as user. Make sure that you are using an up-to-date repository. http://www.miktex.org/pkg/repositories.

Comment: Yes, this worked. Thank you very much. A note for those with the same problem reading this: the Package Manager can be found in Start Menu > All Programs > MikTeX 2.9 > Maintenance (and/or Maintenance (Admin), depending on how you're running it); then on the toolbar, Repository > Synchronize. To change FDNB, same Start Menu routine, but open Settings instead, first item on the General tab.